# Why is PlotRange->All and Automatic in DensityPlot so different?

Tags: plotting

Consider the following code:

```
\[Psi][{n_, l_, m_}, {r_, \[Theta]_, \[Phi]_}] :=
 With[{\[Rho] = 2 r/(n a)}, 
Sqrt[(2/(n a))^3 (n - l - 1)!/(2 n (n + l)!)] Exp[-\[Rho]/
  2] \[Rho]^
l LaguerreL[n - l - 1, 2 l + 1, \[Rho]] SphericalHarmonicY[l, 
 m, \[Theta], \[Phi]]];
factor[n_] := 15 n;
n = 3; l = 1; m = 0; a = 1;
For[n = 1, n < 3, n++,
For[l = 0, l < n, l++,
For[m = 0, m <= l, m++,
g = DensityPlot[
 4 \[Pi] (x^2 + y^2 + 
     z^2) (Abs@\[Psi][{n, l, m}, {Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2], 
        ArcTan[z, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]],
        ArcTan[x, y]}])^2 /. {y -> 0}, {x, -factor[n] a, 
  factor[n] a},
  {z, -factor[n] a, factor[n] a}, Mesh -> False, Frame -> False,
  PlotPoints -> 200, ColorFunctionScaling -> True, 
  ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors",
  PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel ->
  Style[
   "(" <> ToString[n] <> "," <> ToString[l] <> "," <> 
    ToString[m] <> ")",
   FontSize -> 24]];
 Print[g];
]
]
]
```

If I change `PlotRange->All` to `PlotRange->Automatic`, I'll get my favorite size, but the quality of output is not as well as that with "All". But the size of plot is too small with the first one. Is there any way to take an output with the size of "Automatic" but with the quality of "All"?

Comment: do you get what you need if you use `PlotRange -> {## & @@ ({#, #} &@{-#, #} &@factor[n] a/2), All}`?

Comment: Yes, it worked. @kglr

Comment: Can you explain it? I'd like to know how your command worked. @kglr

Comment: Saeid,  I just used explicit ranges for horizontal and vertical coordinates. See [PlotRange >> Details](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRange.html) on how `Automatic`, `All`, `Full` etc work.

Comment: @kglr I mean those symbols like ## and @

Comment: Saeid, `{## & @@ ({#, #} &@{-#, #} &@factor[n] a/2), All}` is shorter form for `{{-factor[n] a/2, factor[n] a/2}, {-factor[n] a/2, factor[n] a/2}, All}` .

Comment: See the docs for  [Slot (#)](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Slot.html) , [SlotSequence (##)](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SlotSequence.html), [Function (&)](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html), [Apply (@@)](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html), [Prefix (@)](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Prefix.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
indices = Flatten[Table[{n, l, m}, {n, 1, 2}, {l, 0, n - 1}, {m, 0, l}], 2]; 
Row @ Table[DensityPlot[4 π (x^2 + y^2 + z^2) (Abs@ψ[i, 
 {Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2], ArcTan[z, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]], ArcTan[x, y]}])^2 /. {y -> 0}, 
   {x, -factor[i[[1]]] a, factor[i[[1]]] a}, {z, -factor[i[[1]]] a, factor[i[[1]]] a}, 
   Mesh -> False, Frame -> False, PlotPoints -> 200, 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> True, ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", 
   PlotRange -> {{-#, #} &@(factor[i[[1]]] a/2), {-#, #} &@(factor[i[[1]]] a/2), All}, 
   ImageSize -> 250, 
   PlotLabel -> Style["(" <> ToString[i[[1]]] <> "," <> ToString[i[[2]]] <> "," <>
       ToString[i[[3]]] <> ")", FontSize -> 24]], {i, indices}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use `PlotRange -> All` and use `a/2` instead of `a` in setting `x` and `z` ranges:

```
Row@Table[DensityPlot[4 π (x^2 + y^2 + z^2) (Abs@ψ[i, 
  {Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2], ArcTan[z, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]], ArcTan[x, y]}])^2 /. {y -> 0}, 
    {x, -factor[i[[1]]] a/2, factor[i[[1]]] a/2},
    {z, -factor[i[[1]]] a/2, factor[i[[1]]] a/2},
    Mesh -> False, Frame -> False, PlotPoints -> 200, 
    ColorFunctionScaling -> True, ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", 
    PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 250, 
    PlotLabel -> Style["(" <> ToString[i[[1]]] <> "," <> ToString[i[[2]]] <> "," <>
       ToString[i[[3]]] <> ")", FontSize -> 24]], {i, indices}]
```

> same picture